# I could swim, I could drive a car,

Tags: modal-verbs

Person A: What are you skills?

Person B: I **can** swim, I **can** drive a car,...

We list them using "can". But can we do the same using "could"?

Person B: I **could** swim, I **could** drive a car,...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can but in a different context.

Look at the difference between the following;

One expresses a reality; the other expresses a situation which either no longer exists or might exist in the future.

> I can swim. I plan to train in the pool today
> versus
> I could swim when I was young but it's a long time since I was in the water.
> I could swim if I had the time but I'm too busy at present.

> I can drive a car. I obtained my licence a year ago.
> versus
> I could drive a car until I was badly injured in an accident.
> I could drive a car if only I could afford one.